# Metaflow: "Missing authentication token" when accessing the metadata/metaflow service URL in the browser

Tags: netflix-metaflow

I’m currently experimenting on Metaflow. I followed the documentation and was able to deploy an aws setup with the given cloud formation template.
My question is why is that I’m always getting a:

`message: "Missing Authentication Token"`

when I access **METAFLOW_SERVICE_URL** in the browser, even if I made sure that the **APIBasicAuth** was set to false during the creation of cloudformation?
Shouldn’t this setting make the metadata/metaflow service accessible without the authentication/api key?
How can I resolve this? Or is this expected? That is, I cannot really view the metadata/metaflow service url via browser?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved under this [github issue](https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow-tools/issues/7).

You still need to set the `x-api-key` header if you are trying to access the service url via the browser. To get the api-key you can go to the aws console
Api Gateway -> Api Keys -> show api key

Alternatively you can use the metaflow client in the sagemaker notebook which should be automatically setup for you via the template.

Also worth mentioning that there are two sets of endpoints: The one provided by the api gateway (which you seem to be hitting) and the one provided by the service itself. The api gateway forwards the requests the the service endpoints but needs the x-api-key to be set in the header. You can probably try hitting the service endpoints directly since you disabled auth.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.